# search string if it has # or . using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to search string using regex. It should search string that begins with either `#` or `.` `(div#element.element)` will return `['#element', '.element']`. However, hyphen is not working. `(div#element.element-wrapper)` output is only `['#element', '.element']`.

```js
var result = document.querySelector('#result');
var regex = /([#.]\w+|'[\w]+')/g;

function splitString(str) {
    return str.match(regex).join().replace(/'/g, '').split(',');
}

var testt = splitString('section#mainSlider.slider.slider-primary');
result.innerHTML = testt;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: can you provide input and expected output more clearly ?

Comment: Parsing CSS with just a single regex might be problematic. However, if your scenario is that simple as you showed, you might try to use `/[#.][\w-]+/g` and then split each match with `/(?=[#.-])/`. Something like `string.match(/[#.][\w-]+/g).map(x => x.split(/(?=[#.-])/) )`

Comment: `if (string[0] === '.' || string[0] === '#')` is more clear and readable and possibly performant

Answer (score 0):

Below is a snippet that will capture what you want:

```js
const regex = /([#.][A-Za-z|-]+)/g
const s = '(div#element.element-wrapper)'
console.log(s.match(regex))
```